# Characteristic of $R/A$ is the same as the characteristic of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain with positive characteristic and $A$ a proper ideal of $R$. Show that the characteristic of $R/A$ is the same as the characteristic of $R$.

**Attempt**

Let $n$ be the characteristic of $R$ and $m$ be the characteristic of $R/A$. For any $a+A \in R/A$, $n(1+A) = n\cdot 1 +A = A.$ Hence, $m \leq n$. If $m$ is the characteristic of $R/A$, then $A = m\cdot 1 +A \implies m\cdot 1\in A$.

What is the possible continuation to this? Is there another way to prove this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that the characteristic of an integral domain is either $0$ or $p$, where $p$ is a prime number? If yes, then in your proof $n$ is prime and by the first line of argument you are getting that $m | n$. See if you can complete it now.

Answer (score 2):

You have made great progress. You know that $m \in A$ and and $R$ has characteristic $n$ which is necessarily prime because $R$ is an integral domain. Since $m \in A$ every multiple of $m$ is also in $A$. If $0 < m < n$ then $m$ and $n$ must (since $n$ is prime) be coprime. By Bézout's identity there is some $k$ so that $k m \equiv 1 \bmod n$. In other words $1 \in A$ as well. But $A$ is a proper ideal, a contradiction. We conclude that $m = n$.